# Push to a nested array in Mongo with Laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, mongodb-query, jenssegers-mongodb

I have a structure of MongoDB that looks like this:

```
Object_id {
    workflow {
        tree_id {
            other_ids {...}
            other_ids {...}
            other_ids {...}
            subscribers {
                subscriber_id {
                    email : value
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It can be clearly seen on this screen:

[My MongoDB structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9u27o.png)

I want to add an another field, for example `name : last_name`, under the `email : value`. I tried it by using this code:

`Model::where('_id', '5adde78993def907b71ce503')->push(array('workflow.5ace115a93def953d254b502.subscribers.5ad09c2993def90a2c59fa59' => ['test' => 'testvalue']));`

However, this code doesn't work. It shows me an error saying:

> The field 'workflow.5ace115a93def953d254b502.subscribers.5ad09c2993def90a2c59fa59' must be an array but is of type object in document {_id: ObjectId('5adde78993def907b71ce503')}

Updating with `['upsert' => true]` also doesn't work, because this method removes my collection and adds data. How can I add something to this array?

Answer (score 0):

Structure shown by you does not have any array in it. All are document or sub documents. you can not perform array operation on non array objects. To treat Subscriber_id as an array , it should be something like this

subscriber_id [{
                    email : value
                    }]

Answer (score 0):

Model::where('_id', '5adde78993def907b71ce503')->push('workflow.5ace115a93def953d254b502.subscribers.5ad09c2993def90a2c59fa59' => ['test' => 'testvalue']);

please try this.